# How to obtain HighCharts series "id" from "series" elements?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I use highcharts.js and I specified an id while creating series:

```
var series = [];
var key = "123";
var chartObject = {
    type: 'line',
    id: key,
    name: "NAME"
    data: [],
};

/// filling chartObject.data array
series.push(chartObject);
/// later this array of objects assigned as series property 
/// in HighCharts.Chart() configuration
```

Later I needed to iterate over all series, that I do using cycle

```
// chart is my object made elsewhere with chart = new Highcharts.Chart({...});
var cs = chart.series;

angular.forEach(chart.series, function (s) {
    // Here I want to know series ID to set visibility to true or false.
    s.setVisible(false);
    // debug
    console.log(s.name); // WORKS OK
    console.log(s.id);; // RETURNS UNDEFINED
});
```

How I can obtain 'id'  from "series" object?

Answer (score 3):

Given your placement of the `id` attribute, like this:

```
series = {
    type: 'line',
    id: 'myid',
    name: 'my name',
    data: [],
}
```

You can fetch it for any given series index `x` like this:

```
chart.series[x].options.id
```